# Reading from SQLite - FMDB - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

I am trying to read from a database file (performing a simple select all functions).

I am using FMDB.

Here's how i created the DB;

```
Pro:~ dd$ sqlite3 db.db
SQLite version 3.7.7 2011-06-25 16:35:41
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table cus(id integer primary key, firstname varchar(30));
sqlite> inser into cus(firstname)values('f');
Error: near "inser": syntax error
sqlite> insert into cus(firstname)values('f');
sqlite> select * from cus;
1|f
sqlite>
```

I copied the file (db.db) to my resource folder in xCode. changed the name of the db file to db.db in the app delegate. Code for my program is exactly yhe same as [this tutorial.](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/836_Persisting_iOS_Application_Data_in_SQLite_Database_Using_FMDB.aspx)

Here's the code ;

```
-(NSMutableArray *) getCustomers
{
    NSMutableArray *customers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    NSString * path = [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]databasePath];
    NSLog(@"DB path %@ ",path);
    FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];

    [db open];

    FMResultSet *results = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM cus"];
     NSLog(@"result %@ ",results);
    while([results next]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"result %@ ",results);
        Customer *customer = [[Customer alloc] init];

        customer.customerId = [results intForColumn:@"id"];
        customer.firstName = [results stringForColumn:@"firstname"];

        [customers addObject:customer];

    }

    [db close];

    return customers; 

}
```

My problem;

Eventhough there is 1 record in the DB, the result of the `Select` statement is `NULL`. Why is this and how can i correct it ?

Comment: Can you execute query with one more parameter **error** statement from https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb Executing queries returns an FMResultSet object if successful, and nil upon failure. Like executing updates, there is a variant that accepts an NSError ** parameter. Otherwise you should use the -lastErrorMessage and -lastErrorCode methods to determine why a query failed.

Comment: I agree. Use the lastErrorMessage/Code to see what is the problem with your database. You should also check if the database is even created and you're not sending executeQuery to a nil object. The path might be incorrect.

Comment: Where should i have this code, could you help me edit my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the database was created and imported into the project successfully, try the following:

```
-(NSMutableArray *) getCustomers
{
 NSMutableArray *customers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 NSString * path = [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]databasePath];
 NSLog(@"DB path %@ ",path);
 FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];

 if(![db open])
 {
   NSLog(@"Could not open DB, try again");
   return nil;
 }

 FMResultSet *results = nil;
 results = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM cus"];
 NSLog(@"result %@ ",results);
 while([results next]) 
 {
   Customer *customer = [[Customer alloc] init];

   customer.customerId = [results intForColumn:@"id"];
   customer.firstName = [results stringForColumn:@"firstname"];

   NSLog(@"Customer object %@", customer);
   [customers addObject:customer];
   [customer release];
 }

 [db close];

 return customers; 
}
```

Comment: the code for fetching the data is correct, if you still have problems, its likely that the path to the database is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this same problem but was managed to resolve this by setting up the path correctly. So, there could be something wrong in the path specification. Do make sure that your database path is perfect. And as everyone suggests, I recommend you to use error statements to narrow down the issue. Wishes!!